# A way to keep the current iteration of a "for" variable in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
   $.get("script"+ i +".jsp", function() {
       //I want to use i here
       //but by the time the ajax request comes back i==N, but I want the old i
   })
}
```

So I got this code and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it than the one from my response.
This is not about jquery ajax calls, I'm aware there are ways to pass "i" through the event object, I want a general solution better than the one I came up with.

Comment: Well, this is rather trivial question, as well as the answer. By all means using closures is a silver bullet here.

Comment: Another way would be to use `.bind` but that only works if you are not relying on `this` being set to a specific value by the calling code. You can always use a function generator and pass the value to it (instead of using a function expression).

Answer (score 1):

Making a self-executing function to hold i works, but is very ugly:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
   (function(i) {
      $.get("script"+ i +".jsp", function() {
          //I want to use i here
          //but by the time the ajax request comes back i==N, but I want the old i
      })
   } (i) );
}
```